# Bind Model to a View asynchronously in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

my problem is to bind a model, that I istanciate at certain time during my application, to a View that has been created at initialization time. Let me explain better:

In my route I istanciate a View:

```
...
var view = new app.FirstView();
view.render();
```

In

```
app.FirstView = Backbone.View.extend({

   initialize: function(){
     ...
     this.SidebarView = new app.SidebarView(); 
   }
... });
```

At certain time X during my application I have this behaviour in an another view:

```
app.AnotherView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...
   onClickHandler: function(){
      var aModel = app.aModel();
      var view = app.aView({ model: aModel });
   }
})
```

My problem now, is to bind `aModel` defined in the `onClickHandler` to `SidebarView` which I created and bounded to the `FirstView` at initialization time.

Please tell me if something is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `app.FirstView.SideBarView.model = aModel`

Comment: theoretically I could try this solution, but I would like to avoid accessing through global variable

Comment: Understandable, you could use events. Make AnotherView trigger an event that FirstView listens to. The app itself could also listen for the event and call something on FirstView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution is to use an event for example,

In your AnotherView trigger a event and pass to model to View

```
 onClickHandler: function(){
      var aModel = app.aModel();
      Backbone.trigger('model:assigned',aModel);
   }
```

in your sidebarView's initialize you should listen for event

```
Backbone.on("model:assigned",function(passedModel){
   this.model = passedModel; 
})
```

**Note1:** You must be sure that sidebarView is initialized by the time you are triggering event.

**Note2**: Try avoiding Global events , i used as i don't know your code structure.

Comment: Doesn't the sidebarView event listener need passedModel as an argument to the function?

Comment: Guess I'm gonna use this behaviour :)